# How to change font in email?

Tags: php, email, html-email

I want to send email with php and change font in emails. I tried to set `font-face` but nothing will happen and font is the same as default, but other styles like color and background is working.
my code:

```
<?php

$to = 'test@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Request';

$headers  = "From: test@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: test@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="fa"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <title>Document</title> <style type="text/css"> @font-face { font-family: iran; src: url(https://test.com/33/IRANSansWeb.ttf); } body { font-family: iran; } </style> </head> <body> <div style="font-family: iran;background: red; color: white"> <p>سلام</p> </div> </body> </html>';


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Loading of external resources often gets blocked by mail clients (because it would allow to track which recipients opened the mail & when.)

Comment: @CBroe so there is no way to change font?

Comment: Well you could try and inline the whole font as well (keyword Data URI), but depending on the size of the font file, that might increase the size of each individual email you send considerably ...

Comment: Also the CSS and HTML supported by email clients is very variable and mostly nowhere near as advanced as what browsers support. Theres no real standards, its often a long way behind modern stuff, in short it's a bit of a mess. There are whole blog articles and probably books written about how to get html email to look good in a variety of common mail clients. It's probably worth researching if people have done work with fonts previously and how they achieved things. P.s. none of this relates to php mail() specifically, I suggest amending your question wording

Comment: consider the option to embed the font type encoded in base64 using font-face like you did already but without referencing an external resource. Writing the keywords even here on SO will give plenty of results: **font-face** **base64**.

Comment: The presupposition that the _sender_ rather than the _recipient_ should be in control of how a message is rendered is preposterous anyway. Any sane email client will override whatever the sender put in and obey the recipient's preferences (which may well be dictated by physical necessities such as limited screen resolution, assistive technologies, access to external and possibly expensive resources, etc).

Comment: @tripleee it's yet an html content and it's expected to render contents based on the font-family styling a given element. You are supposed to specify fonts already belonging to the recipient and possibly using a list of priorities. But yet there's the chance to be specific about a custom font. With that same objection you should remove any picture included because it's too custom. Of course the sender cannot be granted the way the content will be rendered.. but it can do its best for an expected behaviour to occur most of the time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import custom fonts in HTML mailers (HTML Email)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452202/how-to-import-custom-fonts-in-html-mailers-html-email)